# Extracting from S3 a file path with star (*) sign in Spark python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, glob

One of my files has the following path:

```
s3://bucket/folder/file[1]*[2]
```

Now, when I'm trying to read it, using `sc.textFile` command, it cannot read it because of the star sign (*).

Is there a way to read it properly?

(I tried * , but that didn't work)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide  the code used?

Comment: tried \* yet that didn't work.

Comment: Can you specifically explain what "didn't work" entails? Did it fail or did it just not load anything? Can you share the full spark code you ran?

Comment: Perhaps just replace them with ? like this: ``file?1??2?```  It's not ideal, but those are terrible names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the packages you're using, but with boto3 I use urlparse.quote_plus.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus

Answer (score 0):

Spark uses Hadoop's globs i.e.

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#globStatus(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)

As you see `[]` are also special chars there. Try to escape brackets as well.